# How to subscribe the new pending transaction of polkadot in substrate python

Tags: polkadot, python, substrateinterface

How can i subscribe to the new pending transactions of polkadot by using substrate interface python

Comment: I don't think its possible to subscribe on it, but you can use polling.  
What is your use-case?

Comment: My usecase is that if someone has deposited some amount of dots how would I come to know that from a particular account an amount of dots has deposited in my account?

Comment: By subscribing to events. This should **never** be done through pending transactions, since they can be invalid or removed by a re-org.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is the `author_pendingExtrinsics` RPC call, so that would be something like:

```python
result = substrate.rpc_request("author_pendingExtrinsics", [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another angle, I think it's difference in terminology here. What you probably mean by coming from Ethereum is that pending transactions are transactions that are not yet 'finalized` in Substrate.

Finalized means it can never ever change. In a POW chain you work with confirmations, which gives you some kind certainty, in Substrate you have finality and give you absolute certainty.

This is different than the 'pending extrinsics' in Substrate, which means extrinsics in the tx pool, not yet including in a block.

What you probably want to know is which extrinsics are not yet finalized. So you just retrieve the finalized block_number:

```python
result = substrate.get_block_header(finalized_only=True)
finalized_block_number = result['header']['number']
```

And any extrinsic in block height higher than that is a pending (unfinalized) extrinsic.

Comment: Arjan you're almost right about the concept of pending transactions.My usecase is that if someone has deposited some amount of dots how would I come to know that from a particular account an amount of dots has deposited in my account?